# Optimal table design for a medical center rental service and recurrent shifts

Tags: mysql, datetime, table, database-design

I'm trying to figure out the optimal design for the following situation I'm being presented. I'm developing a medical web application with **MySQL** as db engine.
A medical center has 14-16 offices/rooms that are rented (monthly rate) to doctors from
various medical specialties or areas: oncologists, physical
therapists, general practitioners, psychologists, etc.

All the areas have their session time assignment: oncol. -> 30 minutes, psycho. -> 45 minutes and so on.
All the patients do long treatments, so 99.9% of assigned **shifts** are **recurring** through time

So, the question would be:
***How could I build the optimal design so I can store***:

- room assignment for each proffesional from monday to friday. eg:

  1. John (oncologist): MON 15:00 to 20:00, TU: 09:00 to 12:00, WED: 08:00 to 13:00
  2. Mary (psychologist): MON 09:00 to 12:00 and 16:00 to 19:00, THU: 08:00 to 13:00
  3. Michael (general): FRI: 10:00 to 16:00
  4. Henry (dentist): TU: 09:00 to 12:00 and 14:00 to 19:00, WED: 09:00 to 12:00
- Each proffesional can change their assigned days (in case there's an office available at the desired day/time) through the months, so I'd be able to keep historical data like:
  *Which patients had Dr. Phillips treated in Nov. 2013, on which rooms he worked, and which days/hours had been rented to him on that time, etc.*

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a bookings table like this:

```
bookings
--------
  id (PK)
  user_id (FK to table with all medical professionals)
  room_id (FK to table with all rooms)
  start_date - datetime value
  end_date - datetime value
```

This structure will let you track which professional is using which room, and when:

```
bookings
--------
id  | user_id  | room_id  | start_date    | end_date
---------------------------------------------------------
1   | 001      | 123      | 20140101T1030 | 20140101T1045
2   | 001      | 123      | 20140101T1100 | 20140101T1115
3   | 002      | 120      | 20140101T1000 | 20140101T1100
```

To track historic data, you'll probably want to use "soft" deletes on rooms and professionals so that even if you decide to delete Dr. Phillips from the list of current renters, you can still look up when he used which rooms. Your application will have to be smart enough to not create new bookings with professionals/rooms that are marked as "deleted".

```
professionals
-------------
  id
  name
  deleted
  (other fields...)

rooms
-----
  id
  deleted
  (other fields)
```

Example:

```
professionals
-------------
id  | name       | deleted
----+------------+--------
1   | Dr. Philips| N
2   | Dr. Nick R.| Y

rooms
-----
id  | deleted
----+--------
123 | N
120 | N
837 | Y
```

To handle recurring appointments, you could start with something like this:

```
recurring_bookings
------------------
  id (PK)
  user_id (FK to med. professionals)
  room_id (FK to rooms)
  day_of_week (could be FK to table/enum of days of week)
  start_time
  end_time (or you could have a "duration", in minutes, if you prefer)
  start_of_recurrence
  end_of_recurrence

recurring_bookings
------------------
id   | user_id    | room_id   | day_of_week | start_time | end_time | start_of_recurrence | end_of_recurrence
-----+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+----------+---------------------+------------------
1    | 001        | 120       | MONDAY      | 1030       | 1100     | 2014-01-01          | 2014-12-31
2    | 001        | 120       | WEDNESDAY   | 1030       | 1100     | 2014-01-01          | 2014-12-31
```

The above example shows a user with a recurring booking every monday and wednesday in room 120, running from 10:30 to 11:00 AM. It also shows that the period over which both recurrences are defined runs from 2014-01-01 to 2014-12-31

The tricky part is handling exceptions. For example, suppose a user wants to eliminate only *one* instance of a recurring booking, because they'll be on vacation that week. One strategy might to think of the recurring bookings table as a rule-set which can be used to populate *real* bookings into the main bookings table. So that way, you use `recurring_bookings` to populate all appointments for a user in `bookings`, and then *rmeove* or *modify* them from `bookings` as needed. This requires you to pre-populate a lot of data into your main `bookings` table (based on `start_of_recurrence` and `end_of_recurrence`), which you may or may not want to do, for recurring appointments. To handle open-ended recurring appointments, it might require a bit more work. Also, the above example assumes all recurring bookings are weekly. Some of them may be daily or yearly or monthly, and may have conditions such as "first Wednesday of every month".

I will admit that I haven't tried to build a system with *recurring* bookings like this, so this design should be considered a *suggestion* for a *starting* point. It will probably need some work. To get an idea of one way this is done, try creating and then manipulating recurring appointments in Outlook (if you have access to it).

Comment: Thanks for your help. What do you think about adding an "active" (bool) field in the bookings table, so I know that rental is historical or not?

Comment: @Enrique: Could you just compare the start and end time of the current date to see if the booking is in the past, present, or future? Or is that not quite what you meant?

Comment: The booking is made until something happens, so in fact I wouldn't need the end_date field. Something that could trigger change would be: changing day/time assigned, changing office assigned. Some proffessionals get other jobs and need to re-arrange time/offices, etc.

Comment: @Enrique: Maybe instead of end_date you'd want a field to track duration of use? You still need a way to know if two bookings may potentially overlap, so you'd need end_date or duration (from start_date).

Comment: That sounds fine. Finally, which fields could I add to track the weekly schedule for each proffessional? eg: Dr.OZ: every MON 08:00-12:00, TU 14:00-20:00, FRI 08:00-11:00. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If you want to track the idea that appointments can recur, I'd do that in a separate table. I can post details on that later...

Comment: and also have to verify if the appointment can be inserted in the doctor's schedule in case he has available time. Found this and looks interesting http://forums.mcapoint.com/Thread-MySQL-Doctors-appointment-management-system-Database-Schema-Structure

Comment: @Enrique: I've updated with a bit about how to handle recurring bookings.